# Are there tourist information offices in Cancun, Mexico?

Tags: planning, mexico, cancun

When I was in Europe, nearly every city, big or small, had an official tourist office. When I get to Cancun, the first thing I need to figure out is how to get airplane tickets to Cuba. However, I can't seem to find a tourist office via Google, only travel agencies. Are there official tourist offices in Cancun?

Comment: Warning: There is also a density of about 5 touts per square meter who are more than happy to give you just about anything to "help"
 you on your vacation, if you'll just come to a short little sales presentation...

Comment: @AffableGeek What do you mean if I just go to a short little sales presentation?

Comment: Just about every hotel in Cancun is affiliated with some sort of timeshare* opportunity. (Not one of them will admit to being a timeshare, but it's basically that idea).  And, the touts trying to fill these sales meetings are everywhere.  They will give you anywhere from $50 - $150 worth of credits to attend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There sure is](http://cancuntoday.net/services/tourism.php).

**Tourism Information Center**

(Fonatur) Ph: 84 29 59;

Downtown Ave. Nader at Ave.

Coba, SM 5

This is [confirmed in another forum](http://forum.virtualtourist.com/Cancun-959663-5-10131898/Tourist-Information-and-Bike-hire-in-Cancun.html), although it's worth noting that apparently they shorten street names, so the actual street name is Avenida Carlos Nader.